# socket.io-stream error: stream has already been sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, stream

I'm attempting to pipe binary data from one client's 256x256 canvas to a canvas on another client, through a node.js server with socket.io-stream.

In my server:

```
ss(socket).on('blatin', function(stream, data) {
    var outgoingstream = ss.createStream();
    ss(remote).emit('blatout', outgoingstream);
    stream.pipe(outgoingstream);
});
```

In the source client:

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    sendBlat();
});

var socket = io();
var stream = ss.createStream();
var imageBuffer = new ss.Buffer(256*256*4);

function sendBlat() {
    console.log('blatting'); 
    // send buffer to the server
    imageBuffer.set(ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data);
    stream.write(imageBuffer);
    ss(socket).emit('blatin', stream);
    return false;
}
```

And in the destination client:

```
ss(socket).on('blatout', function(stream, data)
    stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
        imageData.data.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(chunk));
        ctx.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
    });
});
```

… this works, but is quite slow, and in my source client's console I see this error repeated over and over:

```
socket.io-stream.js:794 Uncaught Error: stream has already been sent.
```

So I'm clearly not handling the stream properly. What step(s) am I missing?

**Notes:**

- It's very easy to fill the buffer and watch it slowly empty out into the destination client.
  – It's also very easy to overload the server until it stops responding.
- Throttling `sendBlat()` doesn't help.
- Sending canvas ImageData is the goal, not the drawing app – the app is just a proof of concept.
- MacOS/Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You're re-emitting and re-pipeing the stream every time you write to it, and you don't need to do that!

The socket.io-stream examples assume that you're uploading new files (and therefore new streams) every time, each of which need a new `emit()` to get to the server, and a new `pipe()` to go anywhere else.

But in your case, you can simply re-write to the same stream over and over, which means you only need to `emit()` once from the source client, and `pipe()` once on the server.

Server:

```
var outgoingstream = ss.createStream();
ss(remote).emit('blatout', outgoingstream);
ss(socket).on('blatin', function(stream, data) {
  stream.pipe(outgoingstream);
});
```

Source client:

```
var socket = io();
var stream = ss.createStream();
ss(socket).emit('blatin', stream);

var imageBuffer = new ss.Buffer(256*256*4);
function sendBlat() {
    imageBuffer.set(ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data);
    stream.write(imageBuffer);
    return false;
}
```